# How do to stop keosd when using Docker?

Tags: cleos, docker

I setup my eos environment following this [quickstart tutorial.](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart)

Since I didn't build from source and did not use the docker-compose, how do I  stop keosd?

Comment: It doesn't work for me: damianjnc@Damian-PC:~$ pgrep keosd damianjnc@Damian-PC:~$ pkill keosd damianjnc@Damian-PC:~$ cleos wallet list Wallets: [ "damian", "damian2 *", "default", "filip2" ] damianjnc@Damian-PC:~$

Comment: you need to  know the pid of keosd port that you can get by using : `netstat -nltp` after enter you find keosd runing on certain port after that just use : kill -9 pid of keosd

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. If you want to stop the node, simply remove the container using

`docker rm -f eosio`

command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep everything but just kill keosd.

First check whats running using **pgrep keosd** then kill the keosd process using **pkill keosd**:

```
# pgrep keosd
  23     // No guarantee that you'll have same #. :)
# pkill keosd
```